# Syntax for CSS :last-child - won't work on my code

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I use the following code on my website:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <ul class="nav">
        <a href=""><li>News</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Unternehmen</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Shop</li></a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><li>Werbung</li></a>
    </ul>
    <h1>Mediathek</h1>
    <ul class="nav">
        <a href=""><li>one</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>two</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>three</li></a>
    </ul>
    <h1>Jobs</h1>
    <ul class="nav">
        <a href=""><li>Außendienstmitarbeiter</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Ausbildung</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Studentenpraktikum</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to select every last li-element in the ul.nav lists. It won't work after several attempts. I hope someone could help!

Comment: Gah! You need to put the anchors within the list item elements! The only legal element allowed within a UL is an LI, change this around, then we can get on your CSS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you've put the `li` in a `a`.

With this construct, you need

```
ul.nav a:last-child li
```

But you should put the `a` inside the `li` and then do

```
ul.nav li:last-child
```

Both in HTML4 and HTML5, a `li` element cannot be in any kind of element :

- [HTML 4 reference about ul & li](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html)
- [HTML 5 reference about ul & li](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html)

Comment: Yeah, I already thought so, but didn't now how to solve it. Thanks for your answer, it's the only one witch worked for me!

Comment: @user1693941 It's not only more standard, it's even required since `<ul>` may only contain `<li>` as children, otherwise it's invalid html.

Answer (score 1):

Try to swap `<li>` and `<a>`. Code shoud be:

```
 <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Unternehmen</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank">Werbung</a></li>
</ul>
```

Than I think `ul.nav li:last-child` will work.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to put the anchors `<a>` within the list item `<li>` elements.

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Unternehmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank">Werbung</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Mediathek</h1>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Jobs</h1>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="">Außendienstmitarbeiter</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Ausbildung</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Studentenpraktikum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Then you can use the selector:

```
ul.nav li:last-child a
{
    color: #f00;
}​
```

This will work perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/SLB4f/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is ':last-child'

```
ul.nav a:last-child{
    // code here
}
```

I've also created a JSFiddle showing this very useful selector: http://jsfiddle.net/RhKH6/

Here are other useful Recipe's for 'N-th Child' Selectors: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/